# ✗ Android license status unknown

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

this is my **flutter doctor**:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    27.0.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update using sdkmanager, run:
        "/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager" "platforms;android-28"
        "build-tools;28.0.3"
      or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
```

I tried command **flutter --android-licenses**

But it gives me error:
Android sdkmanager tool not found (/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
detailed instructions.

I've set path in bashrc to sdk:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/myname/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you actually try to follow the instructions? The first message says flutter needs SDK 28 and how to install it, the second message says you need to update. *Did you update*? If not, why not?

Comment: Do you still get the same message?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ANDROID_HOME` to `/home/myname/Android/Sdk`